# Times New Roman variant?

Tags: fonts, times

How do I setup my document such that my equations can look like this: [image: 1]
Specifically, I'm after the shape: [image: 2] rather than: [image: 3], which is generated with the mathptmx package.

Any ideas?

Comment: Liberation Serif gives the Z glyph depicted in your question as what you are after. Liberation fonts are designed to be free/libre fonts that are metric-compatible to Times New Roman.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option, using the [MathTime Pro II fonts](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html). Unfortunately, the free `lite` version does not provide a large number of symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % just for the text font
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
The equation is
$z^4 - 2z^2 + 4 = 0$, 
with $z \in C$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like a viable alternative; thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10):

I'd use the curly italic ‘z’, but an alternative could be using the one from the slanted font:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

% use the slanted z instead of the italic one in math    
\DeclareSymbolFont{zed}{OT1}{\familydefault}{m}{sl}
\SetSymbolFont{zed}{bold}{OT1}{\familydefault}{m}{sl}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsl}{zed}
\DeclareMathSymbol{z}{\mathalpha}{zed}{`z}

% some utility commands
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
\newcommand{\utilde}[1]{\underaccent{\tilde}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-5}{x^{2}-5x+6}\diff x
\\
y^{2}+\frac{3e^{(x-1)}}{x-2}+c
\\
\utilde{r}(t)=4\sec(t)\utilde{\mathrm{i}}+2\tan(t)\utilde{\mathrm{j}},
\quad
t\in\biggl[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\biggr)
\\
\{z:z\bar{z}=4, z\in C\}\cap\{z:\lvert z+\bar{z}\rvert=\lvert z-\bar{z}\rvert, z\in C\}
\\
z^{4}-2z^{2}+4=0,\quad z\in C
\\
\frac{1}{N}\frac{\diff N}{\diff t}+0.4\log_{e}(N)-2.4=0
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

It works with either `mathptmx` or `newtx` (just switch the comments)

[image]

Comment: I hadn't thought of using the slanted font. It's good to know there are a couple of options.

Comment: have you ever had to put a subscript on a curly 'z'?  it's a real pain, better avoided.